# Why does my product between normal and gamma distributions not have the expected shape?

Tags: distributions, python, variational-bayes

I have implemented variational inference according to the model presented in Bishop's Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning (equations (10.21) - (10.30)). The VI algorithm gives me parameters to use in a model where I am approximating a posterior $p(\mu, \tau | \mathcal{D})$ with a function $q(\mu, \tau)=q(\mu)q(\tau)$.  Keep in mind that $q(\mu)$ is a Gaussian and $q(\tau)$ is a Gamma distribution. My code for getting the parameters

```
from scipy.special import gamma as gamma_function # Check if correct gamma function
from scipy.stats import norm
from scipy.stats import gamma


def q_mu(x):
    return norm.pdf(x, mu, np.sqrt(1 / lam))


def q_tau(tau):
    return gamma.pdf(tau, a, loc = 0, scale = 1 / b)

mus = np.linspace(0, 4, 100)
taus = np.linspace(-1, 3, 100)
M, T = np.meshgrid(mus, taus)
Z = np.zeros_like(M)

for i in range(Z.shape[0]):
    for j in range(Z.shape[1]):
        Z[i][j] = q_mu(mus[i]) * q_tau(taus[j])

plt.contour(M, T, Z)
```

In the last part of the snippet, I plot $q(\mu)q(\tau)$ with mu on the x axis and tau on the y axis. Since $q(\mu)$ is a Gaussian, the plot should look like a Gaussian (symmetric) when moving in the x-direction. Since $q(\tau)$ is a Gamma distribution, the plot should look like a Gamma distribution when travelling in the y-direction. 
Looking at the contour plot, this doesn't seem to be the case:

[image]:

In fact, the opposite seems to be true. It looks like the plot is symmetric in the y-direction and unsymmetric (Gamma) in the x-direction. But I can't see that I've accidentally flipped anything. How come I get this result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out that the default `numpy.meshgrid()` functionality is to "flip" the x and y axes. To get it right, I changed this:

```
M, T = np.meshgrid(mus, taus)
```

to

```
M, T = np.meshgrid(mus, taus, indexing="ij")
```

which gave me the desired appearance:

[image]